# for some reason the shared preference is not working

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

i created an activity that sends data to a mySQL database , and everthing works fin on this side but i have a sharedpreference class that works that is supposed to send me to an activity called accueil from the class in question which called contact but for some reason the shared preference is null and it sends to login activity instead because of the accueil class condition if

here is my shared preference class

```java
public class SharedPrefManager {

    private static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "CIN";
    private static final String IDCONT = "con";
    private static final String HISTO = "historique";
    private static SharedPrefManager mInstance;
    private static Context ctx;

    private SharedPrefManager(Context context) {
        ctx = context;
    }
    public static synchronized SharedPrefManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new SharedPrefManager(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void setIdCont(String id) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(IDCONT, id);
        editor.apply();
    }

    //this method will give the logged in user
    public String getIdCont() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(IDCONT, null);
    }



    //this method will give the logged in user
    public void setHisto(boolean b) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(HISTO, b);
        editor.apply();
    }

    //this method will give the logged in user
    public Boolean getHisto() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(HISTO, false);
    }

    //this method will logout the user
    public void logout() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

and  my contact class that i'm working on

```java
public class SharedPrefManager {

    private static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "CIN";
    private static final String IDCONT = "con";
    private static final String HISTO = "historique";
    private static SharedPrefManager mInstance;
    private static Context ctx;

    private SharedPrefManager(Context context) {
        ctx = context;
    }
    public static synchronized SharedPrefManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new SharedPrefManager(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void setIdCont(String id) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(IDCONT, id);
        editor.apply();
    }

    //this method will give the logged in user
    public String getIdCont() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(IDCONT, null);
    }



    //this method will give the logged in user
    public void setHisto(boolean b) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(HISTO, b);
        editor.apply();
    }

    //this method will give the logged in user
    public Boolean getHisto() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(HISTO, false);
    }

    //this method will logout the user
    public void logout() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

and the accueil class that redirect me to login because of condition else

```java
if(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getIdCont() != null) {

            String[] listviewTitle = new String[]{
                    "Consulter historique eau",
                    "Consulter historique electicite",
                    "ajouter taux de consommation",
                    "se deconecter",
                    "contacter service clientele"
            };
            int[] listviewImage = new int[]{
                    R.drawable.ic_pipe,
                    R.drawable.ic_battery,
                    R.drawable.ic_ticket,
                    R.drawable.ic_exit,
                    R.drawable.ic_send_message,
            };

            List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hm.put("listview_title", listviewTitle[i]);
                hm.put("listview_image", Integer.toString(listviewImage[i]));


                aList.add(hm);
            }
            String[] from = {"listview_image", "listview_title"};
            int[] to = {R.id.item_image, R.id.item_title};
            SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), aList, R.layout.acceuil_adapter, from, to);
            ListView liste = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
            liste.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

            liste.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    if (position == 0){
                        Intent intent;
                        intent = new Intent(acceuilAct.this, historique.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else if (position==1){
                        Intent intent;
                        intent = new Intent(acceuilAct.this, historiqueelec.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else if (position==2){
                        Intent intent;
                        intent = new Intent(acceuilAct.this, addInfo.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else if (position==3){
                        SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).logout();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(acceuilAct.this,LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                    else if (position==4){
                        SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).logout();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(acceuilAct.this,contact.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
        else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(acceuilAct.this,LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
```

Comment: you already try put commit before this :  editor.putString(IDCONT, id) ?

Comment: hello thank you for trying to help , i tried adding commit to the setters and it still send me back to the login activity

Comment: Where did you call the setters and compared to where that check is done?  Take note apply() is asynchronous.  Also you're storing contexts statically, not usually a good idea.  Ifyou pass an Activity context there, you're going to leak that Activity.

Comment: thank you Ryujin for the comment i used to to see the error you mentioned in the logcat

Answer (score 0):

you are not saving your data correctly using the shared preferences editor . after you put your value you should do a commit ex :

```
    editor.putBoolean(HISTO, b);
    editor.commit();
```

Comment: it seems that it's not working i did add the commit when it was mentioned in a comment but i still get to the login phase